# ESP8266 + TSL2561 I2C connection

Tags: arduino, i2c, esp8266

My [ESP8266-01](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf) recognises the sensor [TSL2561](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TSL2561.pdf), but the readings always output `65535` for some weird reason. But as I said, when I run the I2C scanner and [plug in the wire I see the sensor popping up at `0x39`](https://youtu.be/0SZCCaBYQhY).

When I hook up the same sensor to an ESP8266 NodeMCU breakout and flash the same code on there it reads it out just fine. I have the wires connected as shown below without any resistors or anything in between.

```
| ESP8266-01 | TSL25611   |
|------------|------------|
| VCC (3.3V) | VCC (3.3V) |
| GND        | GND        |
| GPIO2      | SCL        |
| GPIO0      | SDA        |
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though.

My code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <TSL2561.h>

const char *ssid = "Wouter's Place";
const char *password = "";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
TSL2561 tsl2561(TSL2561_ADDR_FLOAT);

void handleRoot() {
  // Read illuminance
  float visible = tsl2561.getLuminosity(TSL2561_VISIBLE);
  float full = tsl2561.getLuminosity(TSL2561_FULLSPECTRUM);
  float ir = tsl2561.getLuminosity(TSL2561_INFRARED);

  String response = "";
  response += "{\"illuminance\":{";
  response += "\"visible\":";
  response += visible;
  response += ",\"full\":";
  response += full;
  response += ",\"ir\":";
  response += ir;
  response += "}";
  response += "}";

  server.send(200, "application/json", response);
}

void setup(void)
{
  Wire.begin(0, 2);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(250);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Connected to wifi, ip: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("Setting up TSL2561..");
  if (!tsl2561.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find TSL2561 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("Starting server..");
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Web server running!");
}

void loop()
{
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Resulting output:

```
{
  "illuminance": 
  {
    "visible": 0,
    "full": 65535
    "ir": 65535
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a schematic? I can't tell what you've hooked up in your video.

Comment: please post the code, not a link to the code

Comment: Just to comment 65536 is 16 bits of all ones. Since the I2C data line idles high, this probably means the slave isn’t responding.

Comment: @DoxyLover thanks, after reading above I started thinking about it and went another time through my code only to find a quite obvious bug.

Answer (score 1):

Found the bug after thinking a bit about what @DoxyLover mentioned! Those 2 lines of leftover code shouldn't be here. Apparently the default LED on the ESP-01 is GPIO2 (which is one of the I2C pins I'm using).

```
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
```